# Как узнать информацию о системе в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Привет Всем!
Как узнать информацию о системе в Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На делфях это сделать очень непросто. Можно с легкостью получить информацию о состоянии оперативной памяти, имя пользователя, имя компьютера, даже версию ОС, но не более. Не знаю, чем вы там занимаетесь, но лично я вам советую задействовать консоль Windows. Есть специальная команда: `systeminfo` , которая выдает очень подробную информацию о системе, вплоть до выдачи инфы о сетевых адаптерах.

Если немного, совсем немного подумать, то можно перевести вывод, вывести всю инфу в файл:

```
chcp 1251
systeminfo > C:\sysInfo.txt
```

Затем парсить инфу и делать с ней то, что желаете.

---

В делфи все вышесказанное будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
WinExec('cmd /c systeminfo > C:\sysInfo.txt',1);
```

Comment: Спасибо,я тут подумал можно же просто ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('C:\sysInfo.txt'); У меня робит)
Но почему отображается так?

€¬п г§« :                         RCON_PRO
Ќ §ў ­ЁҐ Ћ‘:                      Microsoft Windows 7 Њ ЄбЁ¬ «м­ п 
‚ҐабЁп Ћ‘:                        6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 бЎ®аЄ  7601
€§Ј®в®ўЁвҐ«м Ћ‘:                  Microsoft Corporation
Џ а ¬Ґвал Ћ‘:                     €§®«Ёа®ў ­­ п а Ў®з п бв ­жЁп
‘Ў®аЄ  Ћ‘:                        Multiprocessor Free

Comment: Потому что сперва надо установить русскую кодировку:

    chcp 1251

Как выполнить сразу и эту команду, и другую, сейчас разбираюсь сам...

Comment: Думаю, вы уже догадались, что вот так:

     WinExec('cmd /c chcp 1251 && systeminfo > C:\sysInfo.txt',1);

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос смотрю закрыт, но я все же отвечу...
Нужно определиться, какая информация интересует о системе.
Есть очень потрясная штука, именуемая WMIC. При помощи нее можно разобрать систему на части. Использую в C# ее для получения различной информации из системы. Можно также получить данные через командную строку, как вам выше советовали, но лучше все же использовать класс дельфовский по работе с ним.
Например, команда:

**WMIC CLASS Win32_Processor**

получает полную информацию о процессоре машины.
Есть ALIAS готовые, но можно указывать конкретный класс, который интересует вас.
Полная информация по классам находится в справке MSDN, классов очень много, потому еще раз повторюсь, нужно определиться, какая информация о системе вам нужна.
Вот тут можно начать читать, чтобы получить полное представление, какую информацию при помощи WMIC классов можно выудить:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека JVCL в ее составе есть Unit JvComputerInfoEx.
Еще вот не плохая статья http://www.vr-online.ru/content/delphi-sobiraem-informaciju-o-kompe-2999 
Но опять таки все зависит от того какую именно инфу нужно получить.